# Overloading truncate laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi i try this in my model

```
public static function truncate(){
    /*my some code*/
    static::truncate();
}


MyModel::truncate();
```

but i get recursive call. How to organize it correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? At a first glance you could call the parent's method `parent::truncate();` to avoid recursive calls

Comment: @ka_lin
This too recursive call. I need call 
`public static function truncate()
            {    
                \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::truncate();
            }`

Comment: That's what the original `truncate()` does. What should happen when your `truncate()` is called?

Comment: Yes. It original truncate. I need call original after my some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
public static function truncate() {
    /*my some code*/
    (new static)->newQuery()->truncate();
}
```